# Impdp with remap failing on POST_TABLE_ACTION still using old schema

Tags: oracle, schema, remap, impdp

I'm trying to import an oracle dump while remapping schema and tablespace:

```
impdp usr/pass \
    EXCLUDE=table_statistics \
    DIRECTORY=EXPDP \
    REMAP_SCHEMA=ORG_USR:NEW_USR \
    REMAP_TABLESPACE=ORG_TS:NEW_TS \
    DUMPFILE=FILE.dmp \
    PARALLEL=2 \
    LOGFILE=FILE.imp.log
```

The job imports all tables and then starts processing object types:

```
Import: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Aug 17 11:13:06 2017

[ ... the import remaps correct ]

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "NEW_USR"."SOMETABLE"              112.4 MB 1402414 rows
. . imported "NEW_USR"."SOMEOTHERTABLE"                 235.9 MB  955249 rows
. . imported "NEW_USR"."SOMETABLE3"                 86.91 MB  440513 rows

[... everything works until ...]

Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/POST_TABLE_ACTION
ORA-39083: Object type POST_TABLE_ACTION failed to create with error:
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
BEGIN
 SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEA');
 END;
ORA-39083: Object type POST_TABLE_ACTION failed to create with error:
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
BEGIN
 SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEB');
 END;
ORA-39083: Object type POST_TABLE_ACTION failed to create with error:
ORA-01435: user does not exist
Failing sql is:
BEGIN
 SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEC');
 END;
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 3 error(s) at Thu Aug 17 11:19:02 2017 elapsed 0 00:05:56
```

I did specify `REMAP_SCHEMA` and `REMAP_TABLESPACE`, and the import runs *mostly* correct.

BUT at the end part trying `Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/POST_TABLE_ACTION` it somehow fails using the OLD User.

Can someone tell me what ist going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: This looks like bug 20736385. You might need to raise an SR to get more details. (Doc ID 2224305.1 might also be slightly relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soulution was to import excluding `post_table_action` and execute the statements manually after altering the schemaname to the correct value:

```
impdp usr/pass \
    EXCLUDE=post_table_action \
    DIRECTORY=EXPDP \
    REMAP_SCHEMA=ORG_USR:NEW_USR \
    REMAP_TABLESPACE=ORG_TS:NEW_TS \
    DUMPFILE=FILE.dmp \
    PARALLEL=2 \
    LOGFILE=FILE.imp.log
```

and

```
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEA');
END;
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEB');
END;
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_UTL.SYNC_UP_LOG('ORG_USR','TABLEC');
END;
```